# Windows Phone 7 Live Tile Push Notifcations?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm not grasping the idea behind Windows Phone 7 live tile push notifications.

How do you have 2 projects (one in Visual Studio - C#, the other in Visual Studio - Web Developer) and they work together?

I am trying to create an application that stays active even when the user puts it in deactive state as it needs to stay constantly connected to there e-mail account.

how would I put all of this push notification code into one project? Or do I not need to?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

What I wish to do after diving a little further into this is locally push notifications to the tiles, I don't need to go to a server, when the application updates itsself I want to be able to push a notification to the live tile if they got a new e-mail.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mango, you can change Live Tile information using the `ShellTile` class:

```
ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();

// The first tile is the application tile. 
// I'm not sure if it will be there if you application is not pinned
if (tile != null)
{
    tile.Update(new StandardShellTileData
    {
            Title = "New Tile Title!",
            Count = 50
    });
}
```

Oddly, it doesn't appear that you can access the current shell tile properties (at least not from what I can see).

MSDN has a full list of [StandardShellTileData properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata_properties%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) that can be set.

Comment: Hi, it seems to have no FirstOrDefault method in ActiveTiles, how are you getting this? Thanks

Comment: Try adding `using System.Linq;` - failing that, change it to `.OfType<ShellTile>().FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link, it's from Mix and shows exactly how to use the new Live Tile API in Mango.

What you want to do, updating the tile locally is not possible in the current OS but will be possible in Mango.

[Live Tile Mix 11 Demo](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/DVC08)

Answer (score 0):

Having two projects in the same solution is an issue for how you manage your project.

For Windows Phone 7 push live tiles, it's not required, as the push notification comes from Microsoft's Push Notification Service. So your web project should make a request to MSFT Push Service, which will in turn push the livetile to your phone.

Your app should just register for a Tile Notification Channel.

This should be changing for Mango, however.

Comment: Will, I have the mango SDK beta, which is what I'm developing for, do you know how it changes for Mango, like, can you provide a sample piece of code showing how to push a notification of count: 2 to the tile? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still on the 7.0 SDK, because we're going to be releasing before Mango is available.